# Overloaded functions in C++ DLL def file

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm writing a C/C++ DLL and want to export certain functions which I've done before using a .def file like this

```
LIBRARY "MyLib"
EXPORTS
  Foo
  Bar
```

with the code defined as this, for example:

```
int Foo(int a);
void Bar(int foo);
```

However, what if I want to declare an overloaded method of Foo() like:

```
int Foo(int a, int b);
```

As the def file only has the function name and not the full prototype I can't see how it would handle the overloaded functions.  Do you just use the one entry and then specify which overloaded version you want when passing in the properly prototyped function pointer to LoadLibrary() ?

Edit:  To be clear, this is on Windows using Visual Studio 2005

Edit: Marked the non-def (__declspec) method as the answer...I know this doesn't actually solve the problem using def files as I wanted, but it seems that there is likely no (official) solution using def files.  Will leave the question open, however, in case someone knows something we don't have overloaded functions and def files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code itself, mark the functions you want to export using __declspec(dllexport). For example:

```
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)

int DllExport  Foo( int a ) {
  // implementation
}
int DllExport Foo( int a, int b ) {
  // implementation
}
```

If you do this, you do not need to list the functions in the .def file.

Alternatively, you may be able to use a default parameter value, like:

```
int Foo( int a, int b = -1 )
```

This assumes that there exists a value for b that you can use to indicate that it is unused. If -1 is a legal value for b, or if there isn't or shouldn't be a default, this won't work.

Edit (Adam Haile):  Corrected to use __declspec as __dllspec was not correct so I could mark this as the official answer...it was close enough.

Edit (Graeme): Oops - thanks for correcting my typo!

Comment: what if we are using GetProcAddress() with a dynamic DLL?

Comment: Then you need to use the mangled names, or rename one of the functions and make them both `extern "C"`, assuming neither of them takes or returns C++ objects.

Answer (score 11):

Function overloading is a C++ feature that relies on name mangling (the cryptic function names in the linker error messages).

By writing the mangled names into the def file, I can get my test project to link and run:

```
LIBRARY "TestDLL"
EXPORTS
    ?Foo@@YAXH@Z
    ?Foo@@YAXHH@Z
```

seems to work for

```
void Foo( int x );
void Foo( int x, int y );
```

So copy the C++ function names from the error message and write them into your def file. However, the real question is: Why do you want to use a def file and not go with __declspec(dllexport) ?

The mangled names are non-portable, I tested with VC++ 2008.

Comment: Interesting approach. By non-portable you mean across different versions of Visual Studio? Which would suggest they change their name mangling schemes between versions perhaps?

Comment: @jxramos I am not sure whether they actually can change the name mangling scheme. But I doubt this will work in the same way when switching to another compiler, unless that compiler tries to emulate VC's behavior.

Comment: This is surely only a VC++ thing since I don't think other compilers use def files. Also if I remember what someone once told me is that Microsoft has this dll interface idea where user selected elements are exposed publicly, via the def file or __declspec's whereas in Unix with their *.so files everything with a public API is exposed. They don't have a distinction between the logical public API and the library's public API.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue so I wanted to post on this as well.

1. Usually using

   ```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Foo();
   ```

   to export a function name is fine. 
   It will *usually* export the name
   unmangled without the need for a
   .def file.  There are, however, some
   exceptions like __stdcall functions
   and overloaded function names.
2. If you declare a function to use the
   __stdcall convention (as is done for many API functions) then

   ```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Foo();
   ```

   will export a mangled name like
   _Foo@4.  In this case you may need to explicitly map the exported name
   to an internal mangled name.

A. How to export an unmangled name.  In a .def file add

```
----
EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here

    Foo
-----
```

This will try to find a "best match" for an internal function Foo and export it.  In the case above where there is only
one foo this will create the mapping

Foo = _Foo@4

as can be see via dumpbin /EXPORTS

If you have overloaded a function name then you may need to explicitly say which function you want in the .def file
by specifying a mangled name using the entryname[=internalname] syntax. e.g.

```
----
EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here

    Foo=_Foo@4
-----
```

B. An alternative to .def files is that you can export names "in place" using a #pragma.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:Foo=_Foo@4")
```

C. A third alternative is to declare just one version of Foo as extern "C" to be exported unmangled.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shamit/archive/2005/02/11/371421.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way of doing what you want, because the dll interface is a C api.

The compiler itself uses mangled names as a workaround, so you should use name mangling when you don't want to change too much in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Systax for EXPORTS definition is:

```
entryname[=internalname] [@ordinal [NONAME]] [PRIVATE] [DATA]
```

**entryname** is the function or variable name that you want to export. This is required. If the name you export is different from the name in the DLL, specify the export's name in the DLL with internalname.

For example, if your DLL exports a function, func1() and you want it to be used as func2(), you would specify:

```
EXPORTS
func2=func1
```

Just see the mangled names (using Dependency walker) and specify your own functions name.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3(v=vs.71).aspx

Edit: This works for dynamic DLLs, where we need to use GetProcAddress() to explicitly fetch a functions in Dll.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a language or version agnostic way of exporting an overloaded function since the mangling convention can change with each release of the compiler.

This is one reason why most WinXX functions have funny names like *Ex or *2.

Comment: interesting background with the WinXX comment!