# Can we export the same two overloaded methods from windows dll?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

For example, having add(int, int) and add(double, double), can we export both when build a dll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloaded functions in C++ DLL def file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098/overloaded-functions-in-c-dll-def-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are exporting with mangled names then you can do this with no difficulty.

If you have disabled mangling with `extern "C"` then you have to export the functions with different names.

The reason for this is that DLL import using lib files is name based.